# How can I return a list from a list of lists when searching a string and also force the comparison to lowercase?

Tags: python, list, comparison, lowercase

I have a list of lists as such:

```
allTeams = [ [57, 'Arsenal FC', 'Arsenal', 'ARS'], [58, 'Aston Villa FC', 'Aston Villa', 'AVL'], [61, 'Chelsea FC', 'Chelsea', 'CHE'], ...]

userIsLookingFor = "chelsea"
    
for team in allTeams:
    if userIsLookingFor.lower() in any_element_of_team.lower():
        print(team)
  

> [61, 'Chelsea FC', 'Chelsea', 'CHE']
```

I would basically look for the user's requested word in a list of lists, and if there's a match, I print that list. In the case above, the user searches for "chelsea" and in one of the lists, there's a match for "chelsea" (either Chelsea FC or Chelsea, doesn't matter). So I would return that specific list.

I tried using "any" but it seems to only return a boolean and I can't actually print any list from it.

Comment: should "Chelsea FC" match "chelsea"?

Comment: I suppose if I do a .split() on the elements, such as ['Chelsea FC'] --> ['Chelsea', 'FC'], but it honestly doesn't really matter. I don't mind if it just matches the one that doesn't have "FC".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
userIsLookingFor = "chelsea"

# option 1, exact match item 2
[l for l in allTeams if l[2].lower() == userIsLookingFor]


# option 2, match on any word
[l for l in allTeams
 if any(x.lower() == userIsLookingFor
        for s in l if isinstance(s, str)
        for x in s.split())
]
```

output:

```
[[61, 'Chelsea FC', 'Chelsea', 'CHE']]
```